# Moving data from S3 -> RDS using AWS Glue

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-rds, aws-glue

Does AWS Glue provide ability to move data from S3 bucket to RDS database?

I'm trying to setup serverless app that picks up dynamic data uploaded to S3 and migrates it to RDS.

Glue provides Crawlers service that determines schema.

Glue also provides ETL Jobs, but this seems to be where target source is only another S3 bucket.

Any ideas?

Comment: This article seems to suggest it is possible to send output to RDS: [Connecting to and running ETL jobs across multiple VPCs using a dedicated AWS Glue VPC | AWS Big Data Blog](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/connecting-to-and-running-etl-jobs-across-multiple-vpcs-using-a-dedicated-aws-glue-vpc/)

Answer (score 7):

Yes, Glue can send to an RDS datastore.  If you are using the job wizard it will give you a target option of "JDBC".  If you select JDBC you can setup a connection to your rds instance.

[JDBC connection window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u4X7i.png)
[RDS option window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LE4hj.png)

Comment: It would be great if you would show how to do this in an ETL script rather than just point us to the wizard.